# Listview и BaseAdapter отрабатывают только после OnResume

Tags: android, listview, adapter

Есть активити в котором выводятся данные в ListView используя BaseAdapter но проблема в том, что отрабатывается это все только в ONresume причем с дублированными данными, с дублем все понятно, но почему не работает все в методе OnCreate? Есть подобный класс только c RecycleView и все работает отлично.

```html
public class Activity_chat extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<Chat> chated=new ArrayList<Chat>();;
    ChatMessagesListAdapter rvAdapter;
    ListView rv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);
        // View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chats, container, false);

               init();



    }

    private void init() {
        rv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.chat_list_view);
        requestChats();
       
        rvAdapter = new ChatMessagesListAdapter(Activity_chat.this,chated);
        rv.setAdapter(rvAdapter);
        rv.setTranscriptMode(ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);
        rv.setStackFromBottom(true);

      


    }



    private void requestChats() {

        ApiUtils.getApiInterface().ChatData(ManageAppPreferences.getToken(Activity_chat.this),"84").enqueue(new Callback<String>(){
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                    Log.d("tag555",ManageAppPreferences.getToken(Activity_chat.this) );
                    try {


                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body());

                        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("history");
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject jsoni = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
                            Chat chatsid = new Chat();
                            chatsid.setMessageID(jsoni.getInt("id"));
                            chatsid.setVisitorID(jsoni.getInt("visitor_id"));
                            chatsid.setuserID(jsoni.getInt("user_id"));
                            if((Integer)chatsid.getuserID()==0) chatsid.setChatIsMe(0);
                            chatsid.setSender(jsoni.getInt("sender"));
                            chatsid.setMessage(jsoni.getString("message"));
                            chatsid.setDate(jsoni.getString("date"));
                            chated.add(chatsid);
                            rvAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            for (Chat s : chated){
                                Log.d("tag444: ", s.toString());
                            }}

                        Log.d("tag777", jsonObject.toString(4));
                    


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
                } else {

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
                // progress_bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });


    }




    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
         init();



    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {

        super.onPause();


    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {

        super.onStop();


    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        try {
            // getActivity().unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Exce unregisterReceiver", e.toString());

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Видимо сетевой запрос обрабатывается дольше чем инициализация активности. То есть `onResponse` первого запроса срабатывает уже после `onResume` и следом второй. В общем вам надо определиться - когда данные должны обновляться и оставить один запрос. А также очищать коллекцию в адаптере перед добавлением новых данных.

Comment: Да сделать один проблем нет  и редактирование коллекции. Как мне отобразить данные при первом открытии в Oncreate?

Comment: Я же писал - определитесь, когда данные должны загружаться. Если только при запуске активности - в `onResume` ничего писать не нужно. Если каждый раз, когда активность выходит на передний план (хоть при запуске, хоть при разворачивании) - тогда как вы написали в ответе, только наоборот (`init()` в `onCreate()`, а `requestChats()` в `onResume()` + очистка адаптера перед добавлением загруженных данных)

Answer (score 0):

Да действительно проблема была в том, что запрос отрабатывыет дольше чем инициализация активити.Я сделал вот так вроде работает. Но гарантирует ли данный вариант что всегда запрос будет укладываться во время инициализации?

Перевыложил код по последнему совету все работает, и при сворачивании и при открывании заново.Добавил очистку перед каждым запросом.Спасибо.Тема закрыта.

```html
public class Activity_chat extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<Chat> chated=new ArrayList<Chat>();;
    ChatMessagesListAdapter rvAdapter;
    ListView rv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);
        // View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chats, container, false);

       init();




    }

    private void init() {
        rv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.chat_list_view);


        rvAdapter = new ChatMessagesListAdapter(Activity_chat.this,chated);
        rv.setAdapter(rvAdapter);
        rv.setTranscriptMode(ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);
        rv.setStackFromBottom(true);




    }



    private void requestChats() {

        ApiUtils.getApiInterface().ChatData(ManageAppPreferences.getToken(Activity_chat.this),"84").enqueue(new Callback<String>(){
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                    Log.d("tag555",ManageAppPreferences.getToken(Activity_chat.this) );
                    try {


                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body());

                        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("history");
                        chated.clear();
                        rvAdapter.clearData();
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject jsoni = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
                            Chat chatsid = new Chat();
                            chatsid.setMessageID(jsoni.getInt("id"));
                            chatsid.setVisitorID(jsoni.getInt("visitor_id"));
                            chatsid.setuserID(jsoni.getInt("user_id"));
                            if((Integer)chatsid.getuserID()==0) chatsid.setChatIsMe(0);
                            chatsid.setSender(jsoni.getInt("sender"));
                            chatsid.setMessage(jsoni.getString("message"));
                            chatsid.setDate(jsoni.getString("date"));
                            chated.add(chatsid);
                            //rvAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            init();
                            for (Chat s : chated){
                                Log.d("tag444: ", s.toString());
                            }}

                        Log.d("tag777", jsonObject.toString(4));
                       /* for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrayChats.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject json = (JSONObject) jsonArrayChats.get(i);
                            ChatsNotAnswered chatsid = new ChatsNotAnswered();
                            chatsid.setchatID(json.getInt("id"));
                            chatsid.setchatName(json.getString("name"));
                            chatsid.sethash(json.getString("hash"));
                            chatsid.setlastTime(json.getString("last_time"));
                            chated.add(chatsid);
                            rvAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            for (ChatsNotAnswered s : chated){
                                Log.d("tag444: ", s.toString());
                            }
                        }*/


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
                } else {

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
                // progress_bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });


    }




    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        requestChats();



    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {

        super.onPause();


    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {

        super.onStop();


    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        try {
            // getActivity().unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Exce unregisterReceiver", e.toString());

        }
    }

}
```